# Illustrator - mapping objects around a copied path using Blend option

Tags: adobe-illustrator

All,

I have a path that has been copied and inverted to form a complete shape together.

I want to map objects (multiple circles created using 'Blend step option') around the path using the 'spine' option in the 'Blend' tool. However, Illustrator only maps the objects around the original path and not the copied (& inverted) path.

Grouping does not solve the problem. And if I just select the 'copied & inverted' path to be mapped with objects, Illustrator does not make available the 'spine' option. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you attach a picture of the path you are trying to use?
In order to work with blend the path has to be in *one* piece. Not by grouping it but by joining open points. Obviously it does not need to be closed. Just in one piece

Comment: Thanks Leugim, after join the paths, the blend mode is working! Cheers.